# Josegonzalez/Upload.UploadBehavior could not be found cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp

I have a problem configuring Josegonzalez plugin, i get an error as below

```
Josegonzalez/Upload.UploadBehavior could not be found.

Make sure your plugin Josegonzalez/Upload is in the C:\xampp\htdocs\sunelex\plugins\ directory and was loaded.
```

Error: Create the class UploadBehavior below in file: C:\xampp\htdocs\sunelex\plugins\Josegonzalez/Upload\src\Model\Behavior\UploadBehavior.php

```
<?php
namespace Josegonzalez\Upload\Model\Behavior;
use Cake\ORM\Behavior;
class UploadBehavior extends Behavior
{

}
```

I managed to get the plugin via composer into the plugins folder. I then enabled the plugin in the boostrap.php like Plugin::loadAll(); My table class behavior code looks as follows.

```
$this->addBehavior('Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload', [
            'survey_step3_asbestos_pic' => [
                'fields' => [
                    // if these fields or their defaults exist
                    // the values will be set.
                    'dir' => 'photo_dir', // defaults to `dir`
                    'size' => 'photo_size', // defaults to `size`
                    'type' => 'photo_type', // defaults to `type`
                ],
            ],
        ]);
```

Everything is in its place but for some reason I am getting the error above. Could you please help. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like you haven't enabled the plugin [docs](http://cakephp-upload.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#enable-plugin). `I managed to get the plugin via composer into the plugins folder` you should not be moving anything - the error message is using the last place it looks for plugins - all vendor files are expected to be under `vendors`.

Comment: But why is it looking for this path Make sure your plugin Josegonzalez/Upload is in the C:\xampp\htdocs\sunelex\plugins\ directory and was loaded

Comment: because you haven't enabled the plugin, and therefore CakePHP can't find it?

Comment: Thanks you were right i didn't enable it. I just needed to add the line Plugin::load('Josegonzalez/Upload', ['autoload' => true]); for it to find it.

Comment: That implies (as does your more recent question) you aren't using composer's autoloader [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#autoloading-plugin-classes) - or aren't really using composer at all, which is why everything is so difficult.

Answer (score -1):

Using cmd install below command.

```
composer require josegonzalez/cakephp-upload
```

You need to enable the plugin your `config/bootstrap.php` file:

```
<?php
Plugin::load('Josegonzalez/Upload');
```

If you are already using `Plugin::loadAll();`, then this is not necessary.